# control music player from other ios app which will receive control events from BLE device

Tags: ios, objective-c, bluetooth-lowenergy

I want control music player like `play`, `pause`, `play` `previous/next` song from `ios` app which is responsible for receive control events from `BLE` device. Can you guys give me quick solution.

Comment: What is your issue? Receiving the command? Controlling the music player?

Comment: Thanks. I can able to receive commands from  BLE device to my ios app. But my issue is how to stop,play next/previous song if the user listening to songs in iphone at that time.

Comment: `[[MPMusicPlayerController systemMusicPlayer] pause]` ?

Comment: oh my madness. Thanks, can we answer a phone call or reject call from my ios app?

Comment: You can receive, but you can't reject (user has to do it him/herself), since it's agains Apple's/privacy policy (imagine if you launch your app and block all the calls, even the important ones).

Comment: Thanks again --- larme